# HTTP 204 leads to download in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers, http-status-code-204

when I try to Respond with on HTTP 204 Status, my Chrome browser is starting an Download that fails.

Request:
    Request URL: https://dummy.page/dummyRequest
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 204 
    Remote Address: [dummy]:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response:
    date: Fri, 08 Mar 2019 08:24:05 GMT
    server: 
    status: 204

When I use Dev-Tool to inspect the response, chrome says "faild to load response data" and in firefox I can see one empty line.

My server returns a Response via Java:

```
return Response.noContent().build();
```

I also tried to return NULL at this point but that did not change anything.

The whole thing is working fine in Firefox but when I try in Chrome it starts an Download of "dummyRequest" (from the URL) which fails.

So what I want to know: why is Chrome starting a download and what could I do against?

Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: I would also really like to know the answer to this question. I really don't understand why Chrome would try to download a page marked "No Content." The download fails, because.... wait for it.. there's no content. Not sure if this is some issue with how I'm sending headers or if it's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue with 204 responses. What worked for me was checking the `Content-Type` response header on the server-side before sending the response.

My 204 responses were sending a [default Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) of `application/octet-stream` (from the link: *"An unknown file type should use this type. Browsers pay a particular care when manipulating these files"*). When switching the Content-Type to something different (I chose `text/html`), the trigger for downloads stopped.